# What countries enforce patent licensing deals with royalties beyond expiration of the patent?

Tags: licensing, international, patents

I heard that in the USA, licensing deals that involve royalties beyond 20 years is no enforceable.

Is this common? Are there countries that allow royalties in perpetuity or beyond expiration at least?

Comment: This is in the context of a SCOTUS ruling  Brulotte v. Thys Co., that patent royalties can not be collected after the expiration of a patent term irrespective of any contract. It is a rare constraint on the ability to contract.

Comment: By and large,  country doesn’t do  enforcement.  The patent owner does using the countrys’ legal system.